# Using browser DB with polymer

Tags: polymer, indexeddb, web-sql

I'm searching to use my browser DB through Polymer (WebDB or IndexedDB). 
I've found something for Mozilla but only on the LocalStorage part, not the WebDB or IndexedDB : https://github.com/addyosmani/polymer-localforage but I search something for chrome or best for all recent browsers.
I also see that some people use Dart for that but... If I can avoid learning a new language and platform, It'll be fine.

Do you know if there is a Polymer Element for manipulating WebDB or IndexedDB ? 
Else, how do you think I can handle it the best ? And do you have relevent tutorials ?

Thanks in avance,

Comment: localForage is a library by mozilla, but it is cross browser. See the browser support list here: https://github.com/mozilla/localForage

Comment: I just miss that... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: After a few try, it seems like it's a localStorage-like API. I'm looking with a more complete access, with SQL Syntax